# Static variables vs. Type inference

Tags: c++, dynamic, interpreter, dynamic-typing, static-typing

I'm developing my own programming language in my spare time as a hobby. It's an interpreted language. Currently the syntax for variables is this:

```
%<variable> = <value>
```

**Here are some examples:**

```
%test = 10
%somevar = "Hello World"
```

At the moment you can just declare as variable as shown above, regardless of the type. You can even change the type through the program if you want.

I've never studied Computer Science, so I'm not really aware of the Pros and Cons of static vs dynamic typing. Here are my questions:

1. Is it faster to program using dynamic types?
2. Is there any major advantage to going with static typing?
3. Is this syntax good for a static language?
4. Should a statically typed language allow you to change the type of a variable at run time?
5. Should I allow both static and dynamic typing?

**Example Syntax:**

```
%somevar int = 10
%another str = "Hello World"
```

Here's a link to my GitHub, if your interested: https://github.com/reedoolang/reedoo

Comment: If you can change the type of a variable at run time, you don't *have* a static type system.

Comment: This question probably more suited to programmers.

Comment: @CashCow I'll move the question to there.

Comment: note my "probably". You should check it won't get closed there. It definitely will be here

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 4 is no, that goes against the definition of it being a statically typed language.

The others questions are subjective.